# after check for implementation, how to allow method from interface?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm struggling to title this question, but basically this is what is happening. I am implementing a bubblesort algorithm, but obviously, it requires the `compareTo` method, part of the `Comparable` interface. So in my method, I added the following:

```
if(!(array[0] instanceof Comparable)) // dont allow non-comparable objects
     return;
```

So now on `array[j]`, I'll need to call `array[j].compareTo(array[i+j])`.
But when I do this, there is an error saying that the object does not have `compareTo`. But I know it does! How can I fix this?

Comment: Use generics: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(T[] array) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it

```
((Comparable)array[j]).compareTo(array[i+j])
```

Anyway it's not proper approach to fix this issue. Instead, your array should be `Comparable[]` or the type of array should either inherit from this interface or require `compareTo` method